# Xilinx SDK & Stack Size: How to see/set it

Tags: xilinx

I suspect I'm having a stack overflow issue. I'm using the Xilinx SDK on a Zynq 7020 but I can't be sure.

How do I find out what the stack size is that the Xilinx SDK is using, and then how do I change it?

Note that I'm using the GNU toolchain

Answer (score 4):

In the SDK Project Explorer:

- Expand the create application/src folder
- Open the lscript.ld file
- Edit the Stack and other memory settings in the opened
  window

[image: Screenshot of SDK showing edit options]